# Button is not doing anything

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I'm trying to make a converter which can convert mile to km and vice versa, now the problem is whenever I'm clicking the button nothing is happening. The values just stayed the same whatsoever.

My Code is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Distance extends Fragment {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_distance, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button12);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        final EditText editText2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editText.getText() != null && editText2.getText() == null) {
                    String s = editText.getText().toString();
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) * 0.621371;
                    editText2.setText(d.toString());
                } else if (editText2.getText() != null && editText.getText() == null) {
                    String s = editText2.getText().toString();
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) / 0.621371;
                    editText.setText(d.toString());
                }

            }
        });
        return v;
    }


}
```

Comment: the second edittext might not be null

Comment: `getText()` never returns `null`. Worst case scenario it returns an emtpy list.

Comment: It is null...i have checked

Comment: @EdsonMenegatti then what it returns..?, If i have to check if its empty

Comment: editText2.getText().toString()...this will return an empty string. not a null value

Comment: @AlpitAnand Copy my answer, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your if-else conditions to this.

```
if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("") && editText2.getText().toString.equals("")) {
```

And similarly the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i want to ask one more thing, If i have multiple edittext and i want to convert one kilometer in mile,inches,cm,lightyears...etc. The if() condition would be very long,is there a way to avoid it.?

Comment: @AlpitAnand get values of all the edittexts in an array in the event handler and iterate upon them as you want.

Comment: no actully user just need to enter one value in any of the editext and with the click of a button it should convert it in every other value,Thats what i want. :-(

Comment: Then create a common on text change listener for all edittexts and make use of tags to identify which one is changed. Accordingly update other edittexts as the user types

Answer (score 1):

First declare globally:

```
EditText editText ;
EditText editText2;
```

Then in onCreateView:

```
 editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
 editText2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
```

Finally, Use this code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editText.getText().toString().equals("") && editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    String s = editText.getText().toString();
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) * 0.621371;
                    editText2.setText(d.toString());
                } else if (editText2.getText().toString().equals("") && editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    String s = editText2.getText().toString();
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) / 0.621371;
                    editText.setText(d.toString());
                }

            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your button's callback is correctly called. You should check your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

editText2.getText() == null and editText.getText() == null are always false because getText() can not be null here.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking null, please check with the edittext values. Your code would be like this

```
if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString()) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText2.getText().toString()))
```

Simillaraly modify another condition.

Answer (score 1):

Change your if-else conditions to this.

```
if (!TextUtills.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText2.getText().toString)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && editText2.getText() .toString().isEmpty() ) {
                String s = editText.getText().toString();
                Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) * 0.621371;
                editText2.setText(d.toString());
            } else if (!editText2.getText().toString().isEmpty() && editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                String s = editText2.getText().toString();
                Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) / 0.621371;
                editText.setText(d.toString());
            }
```

instead of using  string.equals("") it is wise to use string.isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

You have already initialized `editText` and `editText2` that's why your both if and else if condition not satisfied and your code doesn't respond .

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
final EditText editText2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
```

And your conditions not matched in below code:

```
if (editText.getText() != null && editText2.getText() == null) {
String s = editText.getText().toString();
Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) * 0.621371;
editText2.setText(d.toString());
} else if (editText2.getText() != null && editText.getText() == null) {
String s = editText2.getText().toString();
Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) / 0.621371;
editText.setText(d.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
           if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("") && editText2.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    String s = editText.getText().toString();
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) * 0.621371;
                    editText2.setText(d.toString());
              } else if (!editText2.getText().toString().equals("") && editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    String s = editText2.getText().toString();
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(s) / 0.621371;
                    editText.setText(d.toString());
              }

      }
});
```

This code is working successful.